# Any way to inspect all the <a> information of a button on website after selenium has selected that element?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

Is it possible to look into the details of a button element I identify with selenium?

I'm using selenium to navigate JS heavy web pages. I want to download some files from these webpages but first I must request the files be made available (which then join a que of requests in a table on the webpage) and after some time (and a webpage refresh) a download button becomes available on my particular row on the table. I see that all the download buttons (NOT LINK TEXT) have a unique and unpredictable reference Id in their href, but also include in them a unique identifier to the request (e.g. in this case '2020Apr8 2020Apr9'):

```
<a class="a-button-text" href="/payments/reports/download?_encoding=UTF8&contentType=text%2Fcsv&fileName=2020Apr8-2020Apr9CustomTransaction.csv&referenceId=80808018362" role="button">Download</a>

<a class="a-button-text" href="/payments/reports/download?_encoding=UTF8&contentType=text%2Fcsv&fileName=2019Mar23-2020Mar1CustomTransaction.csv&referenceId=80631018357" role="button">Download</a>
```

Besides the inclusion of '2020Apr8 2020Apr9' in the href I don't think there is an easy, predictable, and unique way of identifying this download button as the one that pertains to the information I care to download (or .click()).

here is the code I am using to look at the button elements with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # spin up firefox
browser.get('Website address') # navigate to relevant page
get_button_elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.a-button-text')
```

If I look at the get_button_elements object:

```
for button in get_button_object:
  print(button)
```

output looks like this

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="a0c542b6-7c21-4851-bc50-39a5a7362e9a", element="9cb24e04-cdbf-49f5-99a2-fa91df862814")>

<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="a0c542b6-7c21-4851-bc50-39a5a7362e9a", element="28de61df-9bdf-4c9d-aae3-d1658bf0abfa")>
```

I believe these are the three download buttons I currently see on the page. There are numerous other 'reqeusts' on the page without download buttons, but 3 download buttons are present.

Is there a way for me to see what the href is of these buttons? 
my plan would is to:

1. refresh the page
2. create selenium object containing all the
   buttons
3. see if any of the buttons contain the unique identifier
   (e.g. '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')
4. if yes, then click.

### EDIT

```
get_div = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]")
for element in get_div:
    print(element)
```

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Amazon_Seller_Central.py", line 249, in <module>
    download_custom_transcation_reports()
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Amazon_Seller_Central.py", line 179, in download_custom_transcation_reports
    get_div = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]")
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]
```

### EDIT 2

Some have asked for more info on the page. This is a amazon seller central page. I'd rather avoid using anything with broad paths to find the buttons since amazon changes things periodically and I'd like it to not break this whole thing.

If I select the 'copy CSS path' to where a button would be, this is what I get:

```
html.asp - ws.a - ember.a - transition.a - transform.a - opacity.a - border - image.a - border - radius.a - box - shadow.a - text - stroke.a - text - shadow.a - touch - scrolling.a - transform3d.a - gradients.a - local - storage.a - textarea - placeholder.a - input - placeholder.a - autofocus.a - webworker.a - history.a - geolocation.a - drag - drop.a - svg.a - canvas.a - video.a - audio.a - js.asp - js.asp - audio.asp - video.asp - canvas.asp - drag - drop.asp - geolocation.asp - history.asp - autofocus.asp - input - placeholder.asp - textarea - placeholder.asp - local - storage.asp - gradients.asp - transform3d.asp - touch - scrolling.asp - text - shadow.asp - text - stroke.asp - box - shadow.asp - border - radius.asp - border - image.asp - opacity.asp - transform.asp - transition.a - ws
body.a - aui_72554 - c.a - aui_dropdown_187959 - c.a - aui_pci_risk_banner_210084 - c.a - aui_perf_130093 - c.a - aui_preload_261698 - c.a - aui_tnr_v2_180836 - c.a - aui_ux_145937 - c.a - meter - animate
div  # a-page div#sc-content-container div.a-row div.a-column.a-span8 div#reportsTable div#daterangereportstable.mt-container.clearfix div.mt-content.clearfix div.mt-table-container.clearfix table.a-bordered.a-horizontal-stripes.mt-table tbody tr#3.mt-row td#3-ddrAction.mt-cell.mt-left span#downloadButton.a-button.a-button-primary.a-button-small span.a-button-inner a.a-button-text
```

'copy CSS path' for a button not yet loaded:

```
html.asp - ws.a - ember.a - transition.a - transform.a - opacity.a - border - image.a - border - radius.a - box - shadow.a - text - stroke.a - text - shadow.a - touch - scrolling.a - transform3d.a - gradients.a - local - storage.a - textarea - placeholder.a - input - placeholder.a - autofocus.a - webworker.a - history.a - geolocation.a - drag - drop.a - svg.a - canvas.a - video.a - audio.a - js.asp - js.asp - audio.asp - video.asp - canvas.asp - drag - drop.asp - geolocation.asp - history.asp - autofocus.asp - input - placeholder.asp - textarea - placeholder.asp - local - storage.asp - gradients.asp - transform3d.asp - touch - scrolling.asp - text - shadow.asp - text - stroke.asp - box - shadow.asp - border - radius.asp - border - image.asp - opacity.asp - transform.asp - transition.a - ws
body.a - aui_72554 - c.a - aui_dropdown_187959 - c.a - aui_pci_risk_banner_210084 - c.a - aui_perf_130093 - c.a - aui_preload_261698 - c.a - aui_tnr_v2_180836 - c.a - aui_ux_145937 - c.a - meter - animate
div  # a-page div#sc-content-container div.a-row div.a-column.a-span8 div#reportsTable div#daterangereportstable.mt-container.clearfix div.mt-content.clearfix div.mt-table-container.clearfix table.a-bordered.a-horizontal-stripes.mt-table tbody tr#0.mt-row td#0-ddrAction.mt-cell.mt-left div a.drrRefreshTable
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide more details like DOM or url so that will get more understandiing?

Comment: @DipakBachhav please don't hesitate to let me know what else I can add to the question to help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
get_button_elements
```

to

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]")
```

and see if it works.

Edit:

Per your comment - not sure why you're getting the error messages in your question. So just to demonstrate (since I don't have the actual html of the page) - let's say your html is this:

```
buttons = """
<body>
   <div>
     <a class="a-button-text"
href="/payments/reports/download?_encoding=UTF8&contentType=text%2Fcsv&fileName=2020Apr8 2020Apr9CustomTransaction.csv&referenceId=80808018362" 
role="button">Button I want</a>
   </div>
   <div>
     <a class="a-button-text" 
href="/payments/reports/download?_encoding=UTF8&contentType=text%2Fcsv&fileName=2019Mar23-2020Mar1CustomTransaction.csv&referenceId=80631018357" 
role="button">Button I don't want</a>
   </div>
</body>
"""
```

And your code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=buttons))
```

Then this xpath expression selects the right button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]").text
```

Output:

```
'Button I want'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
got this spat at me:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@class='a-button-text'][contains(@href, '2020Apr8 2020Apr9')]


Do you have other suggestions for how I can try this? I've messed around a bit with it before and had no luck, but I'm very new to it.

Comment: @MBS Can you edit your question and add the full text of the  two other `<a>` tags?

Comment: I've added more information but I am not sure if it is sufficient for what you are looking for. Let me know and I'm happy to provide what you need!

Comment: This solution worked for me,. I was able to identify if a button containing that date text was there, and if so, click it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below solution :

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='2020Apr8-2020Apr9' and contains(.,'Download')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

***Note: If you get the timeout exceptions from above xpath as well then please check if there any iframe present on the webpage. If so , then you have to switch to iframe before clicking on above element***

Comment: This solution raised a timeout exception, however I do see a fair amount of info on WebDriverWait that I will check out before bugging you further :)